# Can't run chromium-browser after last update

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, segmentation-fault

I updated my ubuntu ,and now I can't run chromium.

```
padra@padra-Inspiron-N5110:~$ chromium-browser 
[8347:8347:7877547751:ERROR:extension_error_reporter.cc(56)] Extension error: Could not load extension from '/home/padra/Desktop/email_this_page'. Manifest file is missing or unreadable.
[2:2:7877908918:ERROR:zygote_main_linux.cc(520)] write: Broken pipe
Segmentation fault
```

where is the problem?

Comment: Also, as noted below, this has already been reported as [Bug #972285](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/972285). If you could mark yourself as affected on that bug report, it would help get the attention of the developers so they can get started sooner on a proper fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug with the latest version of the kernel.

To fix this issue (and until the update is pushed to the repos), download and install the patched version that can be found in [this deb file](http://people.canonical.com/~herton/fpu_bug/linux-image-3.0.0-18-generic_3.0.0-18.31_i386.deb).

Comment: Can you provide a link to the bug report tracking this issue? Installing a .deb to replace your kernel just so you can run a web browser seems a little...excessive to me.

Comment: [Here you go](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/972285) :) Apparently Chromium isn't the only application affected.

Comment: Always a pleasure.